# ¿Cómo puedo llenar un array dependiendo de un valor devuelto por una api?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

estoy trabajando con Angular y TypeScript. Necesito llenar 2 arrays dependiendo de un valor. Actualmente la petición me trae toda la información, pero necesito separarla por aceptados y rechazados y mostrarla posteriormente. El valor que debo utilizar es el de state:codigo.

```
[
{
    "code": 525,
    "demandType": {
        "codigo": 5,
        "nombre": "serv"
    },
    "carLicensePlate": null,
    "demandDate": "2021-07-06",
    "resolutionDate": "2022-03-24",
    "state": {
        "codigo": 2,
        "nombre": "Aprobada"
    },
    "category": {
        "codigo": 2,
        "nombre": "aut"
    },
    "authorizingCode": 581,
    "authConditionCode": 5,
    "accessPermissionCode": 0
},
{
    "code": 546,
    "demandType": {
        "codigo": 5,
        "nombre": "serv"
    },
    "carLicensePlate": null,
    "demandDate": "2022-03-16",
    "resolutionDate": "2022-05-24",
    "state": {
        "codigo": 3,
        "nombre": "rec"
    },
    "category": {
        "codigo": 2,
        "nombre": "aut"
    },
    "authorizingCode": 617,
    "authConditionCode": 5,
    "accessPermissionCode": 0
},
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes hacerlo guardando en dos variables distintas el resultado de un filter, que es otro array con los elementos que cumplen con la condicion dada. Por ejemplo (elimine las demas propiedades del objeto para que sea mas corto el codigo):

```js
   
const array = [
{
    
    "state": {
        "codigo": 2,
        "nombre": "Aprobada"
    }
},
{
    "state": {
        "codigo": 3,
        "nombre": "rec"
    },
}
   ]

const rechazados = array.filter(el => el.state.nombre === "Aprobada");
const aprobados = array.filter(el => el.state.nombre === "rec");

console.log("Aprobados: ",rechazados)

console.log("Rechazados", aprobados)
```

O la solucion que te dice mariano tambien es valida, reemplazando `el.state.nombre === ...` por `el.state.codigo === ...`. Lo que te sea mas conveniente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar dos listas, una donde guardes la info con código 2 y otra la info con código 5. Recorre al arreglo obtenido por la api con un foreach, dentro de este agrega un if else que compare si la propiedad state.codigo es 2 o 5 y las agregue a la lista correspondiente.

Espero haberme explicado, saludos!